# Hotel in Vegas did not charge my card

Tags: hotels, payment-cards

I booked a hotel in Las Vegas through booking.com. They immediately charged me for the first night. At check in they charged me for the full stay + security deposit. However, on checkout, they did reverse the transaction in full amount (instead of just reversing the deposit).

I also got a email receipt saying that my card was charged as it should have been. But its been 5 days and the transaction still doesnt show up on my Chase debit card acccount.

Is this a mistake or I will be charged later?

Comment: Five business days is not uncommon, but any more would be.

Comment: Funny, they didn't ask you to pay on checkout? :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the exact same issue with a Las Vegas hotel this August. In the end I was charged about a week later. At the end of the day they're the ones who want your money, so don't worry about it.